# Remove element's parent row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with buttons in cells, like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>information</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="function(id, this)">Text</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The function called when the button is pressed does some ajax stuff, and if it's successful, the whole row where the button is should be removed from the DOM. (It's a delete function ;)

However, I can't seem to get jQuery to remove the correct row.
I've used `$('#id').parent().parent().remove();`, as I thought it would go: button -> cell -> row, but it just removes the first row of the table?! Wherever did I lose? :(

Comment: Your button doesn't have an id so jQuery cant find it. Use `$(this)` in your function instead of `$('#id')`. And also 'function' is a bad name for a function.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick :). My function is actually called "deleteShift", and the table doesn't look anything like that - I just made it for simplification :)

Comment: Okay, I figured out my mistake. You guys were right to say that "this" is better, however, the button does look like this :`<button onclick="deleteShift(13, this);" class="btn btn-danger" id="EmployeeDelete2">Delete</button>`, so you see it does have an ID, but I made a mistake causing all the buttons to have the same one, thus causing jQuery to remove the first one it found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnX5J/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>information</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="removeRow(this)">Text</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="removeRow(this)">Text</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
removeRow = function(el) {
    $(el).parents("tr").remove()       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`.closest()` can do that easily -

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

You can remove inline onClick and handle the click like this -

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/2nJYe/

Answer (score 2):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6mMkM/

```
$('.b1').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have done this right but there is no id, if you do this it'll work as you expected,

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

but using .closest() is recommended in such situation.

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```